# Xcode trying to match frameworks bundle ID when uploading iOS app to App Store

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, bundle-identifier

After 4 months developing my first iOS app, it's time to submit it to the `App Store`. I created the app in `iTunes Connect`, filled in all the details, set up the correct `Bundle ID` in both `Connect` and `Xcode`. However, I've struggled the last 3 days trying to solve this weird problem. It seems like xcode is trying to upload `Cocoapods` frameworks, not my main app.

After archiving, I went to `Window > Organizer > Validate...`. I see the following screen:

[image]

**The error:**

[image]

(For googlers: No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier '`org.cocoapods.Alamofire`' is correct).

The error message indicates that it's trying to match a `Bundle ID` according to a framework's name, not my own bundle (e.g `com.organization.AppName`). I can't find answers anywhere. I tried doing the following in my `Podfile` (which has use_frameworks!), as well as my different conf combinations but had no success.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|

      config.build_settings['EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY'] = ""
      config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
      config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
    end
  end
end
```

[image]

[image: All codesigning set to automatic]

Questions:

- Are the steps I'm making correct?
- Why is `Xcode` trying to match a `framework's bundle id` instead of just my main application?
- How can I get past this problem to finally submit my app?

**EDIT 1:** I was able to get past this problem, but that caused another problem later, so I still don't have a solution. Basically, Alamofire Pod (from Cocoapods) has a bundle id `com.xxx.Alamofire`. I changed it to `com.xxx.myAppName`. With that, I was able to send it to the App Store, however I can't install the app in my iPhone from TestFlight due to the following error:

```
4/22/16, 12:50:29 AM itunesstored[124]: [ApplicationWorkspace]: Failed to install application: com.xxx.myAppName; /var/mobile/Media/Downloads/5927832272594571027/-6969961974973998640; Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "(null)" UserInfo={Error=DuplicateIdentifier, ErrorDescription=The parent bundle has the same identifier (com.xxx.myAppName) as sub-bundle at /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.IVHCuO/extracted/Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework}
```

Comment: Any updates on this?
There's a discussion on CocoaPods github.
[https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4331](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4331) However, No-one seems to care from CocoaPods team.

Comment: Bumping this, having the same issue

Comment: i am stuck with the same issue did any one found what was wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After quite some time struggling with this, I was able to make it work. Basically, only Alamofire was presenting this issue. Here's what I did:

1. In the **Navigator**, click in **Pods**.
2. Under **Targets** you will see all the frameworks your app is using.
3. Click on **Alamofire** (or the framework that is causing the issue).
4. Edit the **Bundle Identifier**. If your app Bundle Id is `com.company.appName`, write `com.company.appName.Alamofire` in it.

I tried `com.company.appName` for the framework, `com.company.Alamofire`, nothing worked.

Comment: does this works ?  because I am also facing the same issue while building the distribution build that is to be installed by OTA

Comment: @rhlnair didnt'work for you? It worked for me. Care to elaborate what didn't work for you?

Comment: Didn't worked for me! Do I need to add com.comany.appName.Alamofire in Bundle Id list of my apple developer account

Comment: is it in linked frameWork and library ?? i can't edit the bundle id

Answer (score 6):

I was receiving this exact error when trying to submit the app to iTunes Connect: "No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier 'org.cocoapods.Alamofire' is correct".

I finally fixed it by changing the **Bundle OS Type code** to **APPL**.

Comment: I can confirm that this actually worked for me. I had bundle os type code set as a dictionary before. I changed it to a string and then set it to APPL. At the same time, I recreated my provisioning profiles, and made sure to clean the project build.

Comment: @neilge : CFBundlePackageType and Bundle OS Type code both are same right?

Comment: Thank you so so much. Been searching for solution from so much time and wasted my days on it. Your solution worked for me :) once again thanks and Lot... @neilge

Comment: Somehow we changed it while configuring the flutter app. Thus we were getting the same error. Despite setting the correct app id matched with the itunesconnect, app was picking up an app id from the pods, and this error was occuring. After trying this solution, problem is gone. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

It works perfectly for me. I just located Info.plist right-click open as "source code" and I changed `<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>` to string APPL

```
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
```

Comment: Worked! First time this has ever happened. Wonder why that property was missing for this project.

Answer (score 4):

Just experienced this issue with the following error displayed when attempting to upload to the App Store.

> **iTunes Store operation failed.**
>
> No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier 'org.**cocoapods**.Alamofire' is correct

We encountered this when attempting to upload (whilst using Cocoapods) and failing to find a fix, took the drastic action of removing Cocoapods from our project entirely and instead manually added each pod as a framework.

And...... the upload to the App Store still failed with basically the same error!

> **iTunes Store operation failed.**
>
> No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier 'org.**alamofire**.Alamofire' is correct

So this looks like it is possibly an error relating to framework usage within Xcode itself.

Finding that this wasn't being necessarily caused by Cocoapods, we decided to keep using Cocoapods and came up with the following steps to fix this.

**The fix:**

Our project contains 2 targets (ignoring unit test targets etc). 1 for the application (let's call it *MyApp*) and another that contains the network layer and other non app specific functionality (let's call this *MyAppKit*).

1. Add `CFBundlePackageType` (also known as `Bundle OS Type code`) to MyApp's `Info.plist` and set it to `APPL`.
2. Make sure that both the project MyApp and the target MyApp have the build setting `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraires` to `Yes`.
3. Make sure that the target MyAppKit has the build setting `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraires` to `No`.

Still looking into exactly what's going on here, but thought this may be useful to anyone who's currently experiencing this.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I had also same issue while I publish the app using cocoapods.
It was Objective-C project and has been integrating pods as dynamic frameworks.

This is already [reported bug](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=6409498411401216).

So I recommends following 2 alternatives to work around this issue:

- Use static library instead of dynamic framework.
  For that, you can comment # use_frameworks! line in your pod file.
- If you need to use framework, you could try below steps:

  1. Add your framework as embedded binary in Xcode target.
  2. In build phases of your target, add a Run Script:

Example Script:

```
# Stripping framework only for archive
if [ "$ACTION" = "install" ]; then

    FRAMEWORK_NAME="Framework name"
    SCRIPT_FILE_NAME="strip-framework.sh"

    # Set working directory to product’s embedded frameworks
    cd  "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"

    # Get architectures for current file
    ARCHS="$(lipo -info "${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" | rev | cut -d ':' -f1 | rev)"
    for ARCH in $ARCHS; do
        if ! [[ "${VALID_ARCHS}" == *"$ARCH"* ]]; then
        # Strip non-valid architectures in-place
        lipo -remove "$ARCH" -output "$FRAMEWORK_NAME" "$FRAMEWORK_NAME" || exit 1
        fi
    done

    echo "Framework was successfully stripped with unsupported architectures"

fi

# Removing script from framework folder
if [ -f ${SCRIPT_FILE_NAME} ]; then
    rm -rf "${SCRIPT_FILE_NAME}"
fi
```

> Note: please replace your framework name in this script!, you ensure to put this script file named as "strip-framework.sh" into the top level of framework directory.

3rd party frameworks never signed by providers and its duty of consumers.
So when you archive, it signs your frameworks together with your app bundle. But after doing that, Application loader consider your bundle identifier as one of framework. Its weird thing yet.

After 2 days working around, I could publish my app finally.

Even if you could submit by doing this tricky, it will never been installed on the devices.

> Finally, I got a perfect solution and found out the reason. This is
>   happening because your 3rd party frameworks have some issues in it.
>   For example, in my case Quickblox framework has never supported
>   bitcode yet. So I had to disable bitcode in build settings for the
>   main target and frameworks totally. This will fix your issue for sure.

Please review this screenshot:
[image: Disable Bitcode]
I hope this will help you guys.
Cheers!

Comment: How can we determine that framework supports bitcode or not? My project contains 13 pod files

Comment: You can check it in Xcode build settings, just search bitcode in search field :)

Answer (score 0):

If your apptitle has usual slash "/", then xcode failed to sign it, and thinks that I'm uploading first framework org.cocoapods.***

What I did - changed slash to similar symbol ∕

(first slash, next one - other unicode symbol : ∕/)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to remove Provisioning profile setting from Pods sub-project
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First please check your bundle identifier. Next please make sure your app is created in-app store connect, which might be one of the reasons not able to upload the app to the store.