# Xcode trying to match CocoaPod bundle ID when uploading iOS app to App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, cocoapods, swift3, xcode8

I know this question is already asked once [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36511359/5646713)!, but in that question there is only two solution and none of them is working in my case. Help me please. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try to delete this from `Info.plist` of that pod (usually it sits in bundle of the pod) - helped me once with another pod:

```
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
```

Comment: I dont have CFBundleExecutable in my pod Info.plist. And what I write in place of <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string> or I remove that row?

Comment: that string is a value of `CFBundleExecutable` if `<string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>` hangs by itself I think better to remove it

Comment: I installed that pod and see this  <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key> <string>org.cocoapods.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}</string>

Comment: I am trying it. Thanks :-)

Comment: Sometimes it confuses the itunes for a random reason - I had this issue trying to upload update of 1-year old project (uploaded ok N times before that) which had pod with `Info.plist` and this key - deleting the key saved me. I hope it helps.

Comment: No change, output is same after removing that. Thanks anyway, if you have some more ways, i will try them too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123737/discussion-between-mukul-3062-and-serg-zhd).